# What does this notation mean $ x [ f / x ] \equiv _{df} f$?

Tags: computer-science, lambda-calculus, type-theory

Its from the book Type Theory and Programming Languages, page 34 (pdf file page 47)([link](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.104.7428&rep=rep1&type=pdf)). I understand the form $e[f/x]$ which (given the lambda ($(\lambda x.e) f$) means occurrences of x in e is replaced by f. But I don't understand the $ \equiv _{df} f$ part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are defining $e[f/x]$ inductively on the complexity of the expression $e$, first using simple cases where $e$ is just a variable.

The book is using $\equiv_{df}$ to mean "is defined to be."

So, first, $x[t/x]$ is always defined as $t$ and for any variable $y$, $y[t/x]$ is defined to be $y$. After defining for variables, they defe it for other lambda expressions.

Comment: It seems like a roundabout way of doing it, but I get it now. Thank you.

Comment: It's a pretty standard way of formalizing things. We first define what the syntax of our language in this way, too - we first say that a variable is an expression, then given a number n of expressions and an operator $f$ which takes $n$ variables, then $f(expr1,expr2,...,exprn)$ is an expression. That's just a formal way of making sure we know exactly what we are talking about. In this case, there is only one "tricky case" - if a statement $S$ is of the form $\forall x:T$ for some statement $T$, then S[t/x]=S$ - that is, we don't do replacement for $x$ inside quantified statements.

Comment: Yeah, that would have made sense if the author had written down what the meaning as well as the notation. But I suppose the author was going for brevity.

Answer (score 1):

The notation $ \equiv_{df} $ typically means that the two are defined to be equal.